# Open URL in new tab instead of window using c# code behind

Tags: c#, redirect, code-behind

- I have one PDF on my page. But I want it to be opened only when a user is logged in.
- For that I use a popup with login on the PDF link.
- When he/she tries to login using this popup, the code behind it will come in to the picture.
- And from there I have to decide whether or not the user can open the URL.
- If he/she is an authentic user, the page will get refreshed with the user login, and the PDF link will get opened in a new tab instead of a new window.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Hyperlink then use Target Attribute

Behavior for Target Attribute is depend on Browsers

```
 target="_blank"
```

older browser --> In New Window cause No tabbing Support.

Newer browser---> new Tab.

and if You Want you use Button then markup your button definition like this,

```
<asp:Button ........OnClientClick="NameofForm.target ='_blank';"/>
```

in code behind use redirection

Comment: i dont want it to open on anchor tag href.I have to decide the navigation on button click event ,if user is authentic then only i have to redirect to that pdf from code behind.

Comment: you can set the button form's target to _blank

Comment: If user is not authentic ,it will open blank page

Comment: the question is how to open a new Tab right ,please Raise a new Question

Comment: but i have mentioned that , i have to do that in code behind,bcoz untill i found that usre is authentic after login,how can i navigate to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

When user is authenticated, add a session variable to confirm authentication, use that session variable to check whether the user is authenticated or not and if authenticated, write a javascript code as:

window.open("http://www.yahoo.com");

So, after your page is refreshed post authentication, the window will open.

Comment: i dont want it to open on anchor tag href.I have to decide the navigation on button click event ,if user is authentic then only i have to redirect to that pdf from code behind.